# PIG script how to remove spaces in between?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm still beginning to learn pig, so pardon me.
Here's the question.. How do I remove a data value with spaces in between?

This is the data:

```
2 035
356
5 312
62
```

```
data = LOAD 'sample.csv' AS (number:chararray);

processed = FOREACH data GENERATE number;

DUMP processed;
```

How can I edit in the script such that I can remove the spaces in 5 312 and returns as an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution -

```
data = load 'sample.csv' as (number:chararray);
b = FOREACH data GENERATE (LONG) REPLACE(number, ' ', '');
```

I have used the inbuilt filter function REPLACE to get the desired output -

> chararray REPLACE(chararray source, chararray toReplace, chararray
>   newValue) Parameters: source: the chararray to search in toReplace:
>   the chararray to be replaced newValue: the new chararray to replace it
>   with Returns: source with all instances of toReplace changed to
>   newValue

Hope this helps